# Hiding binary values in a number list

Tags: python, steganography

I am attempting to hide binary values in a list of numbers (color values, so they can change slightly and retain the same meaning), but I feel as if the method is somewhat inelegant.  Specifically, I change the list of numbers more than I'd like because of the way I decided to distinguish a `NULL` character (`00000000`) from no information.  So if the binary string as a 0, I change the number in the list by 1.  If it has a 1, I change it by 2.

It works, but I would like to ask if anyone can think of a refinement that still meets that criteria.  This is the condition under which the seemingly obvious xor solution fails.  Following is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
def encode(pic_data, file_data):
    """encode pic_data with the information stored in file_data"""
    # file data is shorter than pic_data, I test for it in the real code
    new_pic_data = pic_data.copy()
    for i in range(len(file_data)):
        # I add 1 to the value of 0 or 1, because I need to be able to
        # distinguish 0 from nothing
        data_value = int(file_data[i]) + 1
        # rgb max value is 255, data_value can be 1 or 2
        if new_pic_data[i] >= 253:
            data_value *= -1
        new_pic_data[i] += data_value

    return new_pic_data


def decode(pic_data_original, pic_data_modified):
    """
    extract a binary string from the differences between the input
    data sets
    """
    # both data sets have to be the same length
    new_file_data = [abs(pic_data_original[i] - pic_data_modified[i]) - 1
                     for i in range(len(pic_data_original))]
    # the test at the end of this makes sure we do not use locations
    # where no data was stored
    return ''.join(str(i) for i in new_file_data if i >= 0)


binary_string = '01100001'  # the data to be hidden
flat_rgb_data = [18, 15, 222, 69, 151, 222, 254, 199, 21]  # the picture

# [19, 17, 224, 70, 152, 223, 253, 201, 21]
encoded_rgb_data = encode(flat_rgb_data, binary_string)

# getting binary_string back, '01100001'
decoded_data = decode(flat_rgb_data, encoded_rgb_data)

print(decoded_data)
```

Background, for those interested:

What I'm really doing here is some image steganography, wherein I can hide any arbitrary file into a picture.  The basic idea is that the picture is a series of RGB values of the form `[(R1, G1, B1), (R2, G2, B2), ...]`.  I flatten that into a list and get `[R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2, ...]`.  This is the `flat_rgb_data` above.

I then read a file of any type, and convert the byte string into a string of binaries.  If one of the characters is `'0x61'`, that becomes `'01100001'` in the `binary_string` above.

The list that comes out of `encode()` is re-tupled (for lack of a better term) and saved as an image.  Even side by side, the color differences between it and the original are difficult to distinguish.  Without the original, there's no way I can think of to even tell that the image has been modified.

Obviously each image must be visually busy and treated as a one-time pad in order for this to work.  Also, you can't use images off the internet =).

The reason I need to be able to tell the difference between a `NULL` character (`00000000`) from no information, as I mentioned as a critical criteria above, is that some file formats use `NULL` characters in a meaningful way.  Usually people just ignore this when it comes to text, as you can safely remove all of the `NULL`s.  But as an example, if you strip the `NULL`s from a MS Word document, Word can no longer open it.

Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: There are a few things I don't understand. Where is XOR implemented in your code? Why are you using the original image to detect the differences, when you can just extract your information from the modified image by using a different method? Is using both the original and modified images a requirement in your project, or something that you thought of for the lack of a better method?

Comment: @Reti43 xor is explicitly NOT implemented in my code because it fails the criteria of being able to distinguish 0 from nothing.  The original image is necessary to extract the information because the data cannot be pulled from the modified image without it; the data resides in the difference between the files.  If you've found a way to crack a one-time pad, though, please do share.

Comment: What do you mean by one-time pad? How and would it be used in your workflow? *Just* based on the code you've posted, I see no reason to modify the lsb of each pixel to be either 0 or 1 based on the bit you're embedding. No need to use the original image to track the modifications, you simply extract the message from the lsbs of the modified one. By the way, if you have a problem with XOR and one-time pad aspect of your algorithm, you should consider posting it, even if it's broken. Especially if it's broken.

Comment: @Reti43 I'm effectively using the original image as a one-time pad (see: cryptography).  I'm explicitly not setting the lsb to the data values.  I'm not sure you understand the point of steganography, because if I did that, anyone could extract the data without the original image.  I'm incrementing and decrementing color values.  If you think you can recover the data having only seen the modified values, please share.  I don't have a problem with xor because it doesn't meet my criteria and I don't us it.  The program works perfectly, I'm simply looking to refine one part of it.

Comment: Steganography is the art of hidden a message in a medium, how you hide it, or what the medium is does not matter. Modifying the lsb values of pixels IS steganography. Someone can extract them in a meaningful way only if you know exactly how and where you hid your secret, i.e. your steganography algorithm must remain secret. If you want to add an extra layer of security, you randomise the order of the pixels you modify (PRNG), or you encrypt the message before embedding. With both ways, the attack would need a secret key to either successfully extract the data, or make sense of it.

Comment: And technically speaking, steganography is about not letting someone know there is even a secret hidden. If someone knows, even if they can't meaningfully extract it, consider yourself busted. Because a man in the middle between the sender and receiver can choose to destroy a suspicious stego carrier. What matters here is that any direct pixel modification (your way, my way, anyone's way) can be detected because of the inherent statistical correlation between neighbouring pixels. So if this is just a hobby project, go ahead. But if it's secret government data, you should rethink your approach.

Comment: Relying on algorithm secrecy is the worst kind of security.  The key (in this case, the original picture) is the only thing upon which security should depend.  This is, of course, just a hobby.  Still, I'd be quite surprised if you could even tell me where the data is in a resulting image.  And I'm still waiting to see how you can extract the data without the original picture.

Comment: I sense a provocation in the air and I have no intention of going off topic. All I suggested was that you can directly modify pixel values and use a secret key (prearranged between the sender and receiver in the same way the receiver must have access to the original image in your method) to embed and extract your secret. If you don't care about whether someone knows there's a secret as long as they can't extract it, it fits your bill. That's all. I just suggested a different method which doesn't require the complexity of yours. But feel free to implement whatever method you fancy the most.

Comment: The secret key would have to be as large as the picture and never re-used, otherwise it can be defeated in the same way as the Vigenere cipher.  A picture makes more sense, because it doesn't look like a secret key so it's not incriminating.  And you made an extraordinary claim that the modified pixels can be found.  If true, that means I can learn something from you.  Please show me how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91987/discussion-between-reti43-and-blivetwidget).

Comment: Good PRNGs have a large state space of seeds. I didn't make an extraordinary claim. I said statistical attacks can be used to infer (with a statistical certainty) that a carrier holds a secret. It won't tell you where or how to extract that secret, just that one might exist. In limited cases it may tell you its length, but that's all.

Comment: I attempted to continue the conversation in chat, I guess you don't really want that.  Anyhow, please demonstrate how you can tell that the image has been modified.  I don't think you can.  Nothing about you personally, mind you, but I do not believe it can be done.  I would be genuinely pleased if you could prove me wrong, as I would enjoy being able to detect such images myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Julien Bernu for the idea; I was hoping he'd flesh out the idea and post as an answer, but it's been awhile so I decided to implement it so others could benefit from the idea.

I'm not positive this is a superior strategy to my original algorithm, but it does in fact address my specific concern so it's worth thinking about.

Pros:

- Modifies each color value by a maximum of +/- 1 (instead of +/- 2)
- Retains the ability to distinguish `NULL` from `00000000`

Cons:

- Breaks algorithm symmerty (must now track which image is the original, or mark it in the modified image)
- Cannot make use of parts of the image with max or min color value (0 or 255), depending on what bit lines up with that color value

Following is the reworked, simplified example.  Note that I had to add another pixel to the image data in order to store the information, because of some 0 and 255 values.

```
def encode(pic_data, file_data):
    """encode pic_data with the information stored in file_data"""
    # file data is shorter than pic_data, I test for it in the real code
    # would also need to make sure that the length of pic_data is greater than
    # the length of file_data by the number of 0s and 255s in it, to be safe
    new_pic_data = pic_data.copy()
    offset = 0
    for i in range(len(file_data)):
        # Now, 1 is 1 and 0 is -1, which still allows us to
        # distinguish 0 from nothing
        data_value = 1 if file_data[i] == '1' else -1
        # rgb max value is between 0 and 255
        while pic_data[i + offset] == 0 and data_value == -1:
            offset += 1
        while pic_data[i + offset] == 255 and data_value == 1:
            offset += 1
        new_pic_data[i + offset] += data_value

    return new_pic_data


def decode(pic_data_original, pic_data_modified):
    """
    extract a binary string from the differences between the input
    data sets
    """
    # both data sets have to be the same length
    new_file_data = ['1' if (pic_data_modified[i] - pic_data_original[i] == 1)
                     else '0' if (pic_data_modified[i] - pic_data_original[i] == -1)
                     else ''
                     for i in range(len(pic_data_original))]
    return ''.join(i for i in new_file_data)


binary_string = '01100001'  # the data to be hidden
flat_rgb_data = [18, 15, 255, 0, 151, 0, 254, 199, 21, 180, 105, 205]  # the picture

# [17, 16, 255, 1, 150, 0, 253, 198, 20, 181, 105, 205]
encoded_rgb_data = encode(flat_rgb_data, binary_string)

# getting binary_string back, '01100001'
decoded_data = decode(flat_rgb_data, encoded_rgb_data)

print(decoded_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: never use MS Word, it's crap anyway! :)

More seriously, if I understand your situation well, the only problem you face if you don't use your idea is that you won't know how many trailing NULLs there might be. (You still detect them 'inside' the document.) A dirty solution (if the annoying formats are happy with extra NULLs) is to just assume all trailing 0 are actually coding for NULLs.

A better solution: could you somehow encode that number of trailing NULLs at the start of your code? For example if you know you never have more than 256 trailing NULLs, you allocate the first byte to encode that number?

Comment: Word, was just a random example (as I think you know =).  Plenty of file formats make use of NULL.  Anyway, the idea of tracking trailing NULLs occurred to me too, but in my actual program I semi-randomly spread the data along the image (worried that it would be easier to tell if an image had been modified if it was all front-loaded).  That means I have values with no information in them all over the place.  Upvote for the good idea, though.

Comment: Even if you use a semi random shuffle, the decoder has to know that shuffle to decode. And once reversed the shuffle, there aren't any no information values spread all over the place anymore. So it really is only the trailing NULLs that matter.

Comment: The way I'm doing it now, the decoder doesn't have to know anything, since I distinguish between 0 and 'no information'.

Comment: I see, you don't randomise the order, just the locations. Well, one easy thing you can do to avoid (using +2 and -2) is code 0 with -1 and 1 with +1 to keep the absolute difference smaller. Obviously, you can't code 00000000 where the pixel is 0 and 11111111 where it is 255, but you can choose your image and coding pixel accordingly: have an image with only a few 0 and 255 pixels and a semi random choice of coding pixels that avoid those pixels.

Comment: You could also use pairs of pixels: the first one signals with a random absolute difference of 1 that the next one is coding, the next one codes with xor. So when you decode, you scan your image until the next modified pixel, then you take the xor of the next pixel to extract your information bit and you repeat.

Comment: Both of those are interesting thoughts.  As far as pixel pairs go, that would unfortunately cut the data capacity in half.  This is already a pretty inefficient way to store data.  As far as going up or down depending on value, I'll have to think about that.  It would limit the usable working space, but in most pictures, probably not by much.  That might be a workable route.  Not that anyone can tell the difference of 2/256ths, but hey, 1/256ths is even better.

Comment: Well, even though the +/- 1 method breaks the symmetry of the algorithm (would now have to track which image is the original, or mark it in the beginning of the data), it does address the specific concern I had in my question.  Go ahead and put that in your answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks for the idea.